# Exibir texto em JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Gostaria de saber como posso montar um texto em minha classe Java, porem este texto teria o conteúdo de um registo do meu banco de dados. Já fiz mais ou menos isso usando `JLabel` mas ela cria rótulos de uma linha e gostaria de criar um texto corrido com várias linhas. Gostaria de colocar este texto dentro de um `JFrame`, mas não sei como fazer ou que componente usar: JLabel, JTextField, JTextArea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para textos em várias linhas, você pode fazer uso do componente [`JTextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) mesmo. Para que a quebra de linhas seja feita de forma a adaptar o texto ao tamanho de seu componente, chame o método `setLineWrap` e `setWrapStyleWord` do `JtextArea`, passando `true` como parâmetro.

Veja um exemplo:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;    
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTextAreaTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextArea Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    String text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of "
    + "the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been "
    + "the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an "
    + "unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type "
    + "specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, "
    + "but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.";

    JTextArea textAreal = new JTextArea(text);
    textAreal.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
    textAreal.setLineWrap(true);
    textAreal.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textAreal,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Resultando em:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No exemplo, eu deixei os scrolls ativo apenas para fins demonstrativos, se não deseja que esse scroll fique aparecendo sem que haja necessidade, inicie o `JScrollPane` passando apenas a textarea.

Lembrando que o `JtextArea`, por ser um componente que pode sofrer expansão de acordo com seu conteúdo, deve ser passado sempre a um `JScrollPane`, senão ele não será capaz de criar scrolls quando o texto dentro dele ultrapassar a área visível.

Comment: Muuuito obrigada, ficou muito legal!!!!

Comment: @Sarah disponha :)

Comment: Percebi agora q da para apagar o texto

Comment: desculpe mas teria um jeito de impedir isso ??

Comment: @Sarah `textArea.setEditable(false);`

Comment: Funcionou!! Tks tks tks :)

Comment: Como chamar isso dentro de um evento no jmenuBar ? Se colocar apenas como classe ele não faz nada, se for main ...